# Convergence from partial sums

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Could anyone help with this question:
So, we're told that when partial sums are bounded, the series converges. Is this true for every partial sum of the series?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is true for the series $\sum_{n}a_n$ with nonnegative $a_n$'s.  Partial sums are increasing, so when bounded, also convergent.

In general, it is not true. Let $a_n=(-1)^n$. Then partial sums of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$ are bounded, but their limit does not exist.